# Twin Peaks: Nature of Cooper and Laura's relationship?

Tags: twin-peaks

The relationship between Coop and Laura at the beginning appears as simple as investigator and dead victim. Yet very quickly Coop meets the spirit(?) of Laura in the Red Room on a number of occasions, first in his dreams and then by physically entering the Room. During their interactions, Laura (and the LMFAP) seems to try to help Coop with the murders and the nature of the Lodge, she kisses him, tells him they'll meet again and warns him about her doppelganger. The result is that they appear to have immediate rapport and even a very close relationship. In *Fire Walk With Me*, Coop even describes Laura as a person in danger and lists some personal characteristics even though they'd never met or had any reason to interact.

Do we know what exactly the relationship between these two is and why are they so familiar with each other even though they've ostensibly never met in "real life"? And is Annie related to all this somehow? (I note that the only living woman Coop pursues a romantic relationship with, Annie, shares a number of striking physical and psychological similarities to Laura, e.g. blonde hair, history of abuse, etc.)

And how does this tie in with Laura accepting Mike's ring immediately prior to her murder (in *FWWM*), and so apparently 'marrying' him? (In the Room, she is then often accompanied by the LMFAP or Mike.)

Comment: I've tried to answer this question several times now, but I don't think I understand what you are actually asking. You're correct in that they never met in real life. Do you want to know how/why Laura "reached out" especially to Coop from the Black Lodge?